# How to connect AC adapter to SATA power cable

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I suspect that my PSU is not providing enough power to my internal 3.5" hard drive, so in order to find out if that's the case, I'd like to use my 3.5" external HDD's AC adapter which provides 12V-1.5A as the means to power my internal HDD. I already have a MOLEX to SATA cable ready and of course the AC adapter (as shown in the images below). So what I'm trying to do is to cut the wires of the MOLEX to SATA cable and connect them to the end of the AC adapter. I just don't know which to connect to which, and what to do with the black wires (which are apparently the grounds? Correct me if I'm wrong).

Your help is appreciated.

[image: Cable]

[image: power supply]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

The adapter provides only 12V, but the hard drive requires also 5V which the adapter does not provide.

At least you would have to find a way to convert the 12V down to 5V to provide the needed supplies to the drive.

Even then, the AC adapter only provides 1.5A of current at 12V. That is by itself may or may not be enough to power a typical internal HDD as they can require up to 2A. In addition some current would be taken by the 12V to 5V converter, so I would guess the ATX PSU should be easily able to power the HDD, while the AC adapter would not even work due to missing 5V.

Comment: Am I wrong to assume that the SATA data cable would take care of the 5V requirement? Because the same AC adapter is the original power source shipped with my 3.5" EXTERNAL HDD. Or maybe the 5V is provided by the USB connection in case of the external HDD?

Comment: No, the SATA cable does not provide power at all. The external HDD enclosure just has circuitry inside to convert the 12V to 5V.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.